# Cookbooks are not being executed in order

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, test-kitchen

I am trying to install resource before I execute my own recipe.

.kitchen.yaml:

```
run_list:
  - recipe[ets_base_filesystems::default]
  - recipe[nexpose::default]
  - recipe[ets_nexpose_bootstrap::default]
```

Execution log:

```
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
     - ets_base_filesystems
     - nexpose
     - ets_nexpose_bootstrap
     - lvm
     - chef_handler
     - windows
   Compiling Cookbooks...
   Recipe: ets_nexpose_bootstrap::getconfig
```

Event though, I have mentioned order in run list. First two, recipes are being skipped. I have tried to add include_recipe in default.rb.

Thanks

Comment: You can run with debugging (`chef-client -l debug`) to get a little more information about what is happening. You might have some compile vs. converge time mismatches that look like out of order execution.

Comment: Are the first two recipes actually being skipped, or have they already been applied and the agent is not re-applying them?

Comment: I am creating new node using redhat and than trying to install filesystem and nexpose to it. Once they both are there, my recipe(ets_nexpose_bootstrap::default) should run.

Comment: Thank you all. I found solution. I am new to chef and I forgot to put ruby code in ruby block so it was being executed at compile time rather than run time. I put that code in ruby blocks and it worked.